# If the admin don't set the ssh service port on default 22, how can i find the port that he set?

Tags: linux, ssh

nmap can't do the work. I have checked that. 
ps: I just use the basic nmap function(nmap host). 
Oh, My god. Trust me i don't plan to do bad things. I am just curious! Please don't do -1!

### update, use command: nmap -v -p1-65535 -sV

```
Scanning hidethehostaddress [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 21:38, 0.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 21:38
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 21:38, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 21:38
Scanning hidethehostaddress [65535 ports]
Connect Scan Timing: About 11.88% done; ETC: 21:43 (0:03:50 remaining)
Connect Scan Timing: About 32.96% done; ETC: 21:41 (0:02:04 remaining)
Completed Connect Scan at 21:40, 83.98s elapsed (65535 total ports)
Initiating Service scan at 21:40
Nmap scan report for hidethehostaddress
Host is up (0.080s latency).
Not shown: 65532 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE VERSION
23/tcp  closed telnet
80/tcp  closed http
443/tcp closed https

Read data files from: /usr/share/nmap
Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org   /submit/ .
```

### Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 84.13 seconds

Comment: wow that's some horrible English,  and the answer is `nmap -sV`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can:

```
nmap -v -p1-65535 -sV scanme.nmap.org
```

Comment: -sV option doesn't work either. :-(

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? In any case, you can try to leave it out, the most important ones are -v for "verbose" and -p1-65535 for "all ports".

Comment: Update the post. I am sure the sshd is open. Because i can login in via ssh. The port is 521.

Comment: @LouXiu -sV is 100% the answer,  you are too much of a noob to recognize it.

Comment: @Rook .... I need to study nmap further